# filtering multiple columns in flask/sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm new to flask/sqlalchemy and have been trying to use filters to reject POST event when a resource in my recipe database already exist.

So I want to check if, for a given user (**id**), a **recipename** already exists. I do this by:

```
exists = db.session.query(Recipe).filter_by(rname=recipename, id=id).scalar()
```

This doesn't seem to work, though it should be if you follow my debug:

In my code, I broke it down and I've put the following lines:

```
print '1', db.session.query(Recipe).filter_by(id=id).scalar()

print '2', db.session.query(Recipe).filter_by(rname=recipename).scalar()

print '3', db.session.query(Recipe).filter_by(rname=recipename, id=id).scalar()
```

1st POST attempt with rname=test :

```
1 <__main__.Recipe object at 0x103cff490>

2 None

3 None
```

This makes sense as only the user id should return non-zero response, since the recipe has not been posted yet.

2nd POST attempt with rname=test :

```
1 <__main__.Recipe object at 0x103cff350>

2 <__main__.Recipe object at 0x103cff390>

3 None
```

As expected, (1) and (2) are not None, as rname=test now also exists. But why is (3) still returning None?

When I drop the .scalar() off print statement 3, the query looks correct:

```
SELECT recipes.id AS recipes_id, recipes.rname AS recipes_rname, recipes.customer_id AS recipes_customer_id, recipes.date AS recipes_date, recipes.done AS recipes_done
FROM recipes
WHERE recipes.rname = :rname_1 AND recipes.id = :id_1
```

I can also select the row from my postgres database.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't you mean `filter_by(rname=recipename, customer_id=id)`?

Comment: thank you univerio, that fixed it! I'd been using 'id' as shorthand for 'customer_id' in my code elsewhere, but of course it's meaningless in this spot. Thanks